# Unable to click on element in menu

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]I am not able to click on the button, how you can see on the picture. This menu is visible, when you click on Tabellen button in the main menu. It is working manually, but when I try my selenium code, it is not working. I try different type of select it, I tried also waits. I tried xpath, cssSelector, ID. What is strange, selenium just click Tabellen button from main menu, but that menu after that just blink and nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this example. You need to correct XPath if I have made a mistake.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Tabellen"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Tabellen"]//*[text()="Standorte"]').click()
```

Comment: Hi, I try that, but its not working. I am working with chrome driver, but tabellen is clicked, but after that i am not able to click standorte. I have to find other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem. I tried this and it worked:

```js
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Menu"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Menu Item"]').click()
```